# \g@addto@macro appending position specific references

Tags: cross-referencing, automation

I would like to produce an automatically generated table containing section names. In particular, I would like to have control over the table shape, etc. (the table is used only as a minimal example). How can I achieve, that the command `\addtotable` and `\currentname` do not get simply composed, but that `\addtotable` adds the correct reference, i.e., the first line of the table should contain "Section 1" and the second one "Section 2" (I am referring to the minimal example below). Please keep in mind that I do not want to give the sections a label and refer to it explicitly for every Section separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\newcommand\foo{%
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
            \hline
            Section \\ \hline % Header row
            \foorows
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\newcommand\foorows{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\foorows{\@gobble}%
    \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
        \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\foorows{\\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Section~1}
    Current section: \currentname.\\~\\

    Partial table:
    \addtotable{\currentname}
    \foo

    \section{Section~2}
    Current section: \currentname.\\~\\

    Full table:
    \addtotable{\currentname}
    \foo 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear why adding `&` just for gobbling them.

Apart from this, the problem with your code is that you just expand once `\currentname`, so you're always adding `\@currentlabelname`. You need to expand it twice, which can be done with a greater number of `\expandafter`’s, but can also be realized using exhaustive expansion, marking explicitly what should not be expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand\foo{%
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
  \hline
  Section \\ \hline % Header row
  \foorows
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\newcommand\foorows{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\foorows{#1\noexpand\\}%
    }\x
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section~1}
Current section: \currentname.

Partial table:
\addtotable{\currentname}
\foo

\section{Section~2}
Current section: \currentname.

Full table:
\addtotable{\currentname}
\foo 

\end{document}
```

Note `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef`, so commands such as `~` or `\textbf`, that don't cleanly survive `\edef`, will turn out to be safe.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow-up question which I posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426625/gaddtomacro-combined-with-immediate-write-auxout-appending-position-specifi.

Answer (score 5):

You need to expand the addtotable parameter while adding it. This can be done with`\edef`: You create a new macro `\exptmp` which has the same value as `\tmp`, except that is is fully expanded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\newcommand\foo{%
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
            \hline
            Section \\ \hline % Header row
            \foorows
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\newcommand\foorows{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\foorows{\@gobble}%
    \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
        \edef\exptmp{\tmp}
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\foorows
        \expandafter{\expandafter&\exptmp}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\foorows{\\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Section~1}
    Current section: \currentname.\\~\\

    Partial table:
    \addtotable{\currentname}
    \foo

    \section{Section~2}
    Current section: \currentname.\\~\\

    Full table:
    \addtotable{\currentname}
    \foo 

\end{document}
```

If you want to do more complicated programming in LaTeX, I recommend taking a look into `expl3`. It adds programming layer which makes it much easier to write code like this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and for the hint about `expl3`. I will take a look at it.