# \g@addto@macro combined with \immediate\write\@auxout appending position specific references

Tags: cross-referencing, automation

This is a follow-up question to [\g@addto@macro appending position specific references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426572/gaddtomacro-appending-position-specific-references).
In this case I apply the automatic table filling with `\immediate\write\@auxout`. The reason is that I would like to position the full table at the begining of the document. But as you can see, the references update all the time and I did not figure out how to use `\expand` or `\noexpand` to control this behaviour. The minimal example below is self-explanatory and also shows what I wanted to achieve. The references outside the table behave as expected. But, the references inside the table do not (I assume the problem lies in the command `\addtotable`). My question is, how can I change the defined commands such that the tables will also be updated correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcommand\foorows{}

\newcommand\foo{%
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
            \hline
            Section \\ \hline % Header row
            \foorows
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%  
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\g@addto@macro\foorows{#1 \\}}}%  
}%
\makeatother 
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\refthis}{% 
         \hyperlink\@currentHref\@currentlabel
}

\newcommand\refthistype[1]{%   
    \begingroup
     \Hy@localanchornametrue  
     \expandafter\hyper@makecurrent\noexpand{#1}%
       \hyperlink\@currentHref{\csname  the#1\endcsname}%  
      \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\example}[1]{ 
    ~\\ 
    \textbf{Example}\\
This is important
Environment example correctly referrs to 
Section~\refthistype{section}
and 
Subsection~\refthis.
\begin{equation}
\label{#1}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
% 
This 
Environment now 
referes to Subsection~\refthis\, instead of Equation~\ref{#1}.
But this is not so bad since we can make a work around.
% 
\addtotable{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\addtotable{refthis~\refthis}
\addtotable{refthistype\{section\}~\refthistype{section}}
~\\ 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section~1} 
\label{Section 1}
Main table:
\foo 

\subsection{Subsection~1.1}
\label{Subsection 1.1} 
\subsection{Subsection~1.2} 
\label{Subsection 1.2}
The references correctly refer to Section~\refthis,
\currentname, Section~\refthistype{section},
and Subsection~\refthistype{subsection}.

\example{Eq1} 

Partial table:
\addtotable{\refthis}
\foo

\refthis

\section{Section~2}

\section{Section~3}
\label{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection~3.1}
\label{Subsection 3.1}
The references correctly refer to Section~\refthis,
\currentname, Section~\refthistype{section},
and Subsection~\refthistype{subsection}.

\example{Eq2} 

Full table:
\addtotable{\refthis}
\foo 

\textcolor{red}{Some of the references in the table changed.}
\\~\\
Expected table output:

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
        \hline
        Section \\\hline % Header row
        Equation~\ref{Eq1}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 1.2}\\\hline
        refthistype\{section\}\ref{Section 1}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 1.2}\\\hline
        Equation~\ref{Eq2}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 3.1}\\\hline
        refthistype\{section\}\ref{Section 3}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 3.1}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\immediate\write\@auxout{\unavoided{...}}` will stop all expansion, but you need some commands expanded.
Instead you can use `\protected@write\@auxout{}{...}` to control expansion via the LaTeX `\protect` machanism.

Additionally `\refthis` has to be changed to allow expansion, you mostly have to add braces here:

```
\newcommand{\refthis}{% 
  \protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{\@currentlabel}
}
```

It is harder to fix `\refthistype`. The current version can't be made expandable without changing a lot of hyperref internals, but you can avoid it with a little hack:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\@currentlink[1]{\hyperlink\@currentHref{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand\refthistype[1]{%   
  \begingroup
    \protect\Hy@localanchornametrue  
    \protect\@nameuse{c@#1}=\the\value{#1}
    \protect\hyper@makecurrent{#1}%
    \@currentlink{#1}%  
  \endgroup
}
```

Combined this gives a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcommand\foorows{}

\newcommand\foo{%
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
            \hline
            Section \\ \hline % Header row
            \foorows
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}


\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\realaddtotable[1]{\g@addto@macro\foorows{#1 \\}}
\newcommand\addtotable[1]{%  
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\realaddtotable{#1}}%  
}%
\makeatother 
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\refthis}{% 
  \protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{\@currentlabel}
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\@currentlink[1]{\hyperlink\@currentHref{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand\refthistype[1]{%   
  \begingroup
    \protect\Hy@localanchornametrue  
    \protect\@nameuse{c@#1}=\the\value{#1}
    \protect\hyper@makecurrent{#1}%
    \@currentlink{#1}%  
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\example}[1]{ 
    ~\\ 
    \textbf{Example}\\
This is important
Environment example correctly referrs to 
Section~\refthistype{section}
and 
Subsection~\refthis.
\begin{equation}
\label{#1}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
% 
This 
Environment now 
referes to Subsection~\refthis\, instead of Equation~\ref{#1}.
But this is not so bad since we can make a work around.
% 
\addtotable{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\addtotable{refthis~\refthis}
\addtotable{refthistype\{section\}~\refthistype{section}}
~\\ 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section~1} 
\label{Section 1}
Main table:
\foo 

\subsection{Subsection~1.1}
\label{Subsection 1.1} 
\subsection{Subsection~1.2} 
\label{Subsection 1.2}
The references correctly refer to Section~\refthis,
\currentname, Section~\refthistype{section},
and Subsection~\refthistype{subsection}.

\example{Eq1} 

Partial table:
\addtotable{\refthis}
\foo

\refthis

\section{Section~2}

\section{Section~3}
\label{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection~3.1}
\label{Subsection 3.1}
The references correctly refer to Section~\refthis,
\currentname, Section~\refthistype{section},
and Subsection~\refthistype{subsection}.

\example{Eq2} 

Full table:
\addtotable{\refthis}
\foo 

\textcolor{red}{Some of the references in the table changed.}
\\~\\
Expected table output:

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |c| }
        \hline
        Section \\\hline % Header row
        Equation~\ref{Eq1}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 1.2}\\\hline
        refthistype\{section\}\ref{Section 1}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 1.2}\\\hline
        Equation~\ref{Eq2}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 3.1}\\\hline
        refthistype\{section\}\ref{Section 3}\\\hline
        Subsection~\ref{Subsection 3.1}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is almost what I am seeking for. However, the code does not work as expected if I change `\addtotable{refthistype\{section\}~\refthistype{section}}` to `\addtotable{refthistype\{subsection\}~\refthistype{subsection}}`. Is it possible to fix that, or define a separate command which would allow to add subsections?